# How to lock Form during lunch a class?

Tags: forms, locking, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a simple Form **MyCustomForm**, in a Form's Button in *Clicked method* I call a Class (method run), so I want to lock (or block) this form during run execution.

My code is look like this :

```
void clicked()
{// in Button clicked in **MyCustomForm**
     MyClass myClass;
     super();
     myClass = new MyClass();

     // here I want to freeze my FORM 
     myClass.run();
    // here I want to unlock my Form
}
```

I need this because when class (*MyClass*) is running can display Dialog etc, but I don't want to touc/click and other on *MyCustomForm*

If I use :

```
element.wait(); // not work well - block all
myClass.run();
```

Thanks,
enjoy.

Comment: Can you share the code of `myClass.run()` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class displays dialog you can make this dialog modal using the following line of code `dialog.parmIsModal(true)`. 
Or `formRun.wait(true)` for forms.

Comment: Thanks @Aliaksandr Maksimau, but in my class I don't call Dialog, I can call, other form othe dialog etc, I njust need to freeze the Firt form caller.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can disable controls on your form. This will not prevent from touch/click but prevent from user interaction with form. But on the other hand you can make modal all forms/dialogs that you call in your class.

Comment: Yes, Now I'm doing this, but if exist any way to block all Form for me it's better and cad do a general solution. Thanks @Aliaksandr Maksimau

Comment: Hi @Aliaksandr Maksimau nice advice.